# Перенести div с определённым id на самый верх

Tags: javascript

На странице есть div'ы с определёнными id. Нужна функция на js, чтобы по событию она переносила div блок с выбранным id на самый вверх. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DD9zb/

Comment: Наверх - это вперёд или по z-index'у?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div").click( function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this);
    var parent_elem = elem.parent();
    parent_elem.not(elem);
    parent_elem.prepend(elem);
});
```

[Работающий пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zzAvY/1/)